# how does an objective-c xmlchar data type work

Tags: objective-c, xml, types

In objective c how does an xmlchar data type work?  I can't seem to find any API documentation.  Specifically my declaration looks like:

```
    const xmlChar **attributes
```

Am I classifying this correctly by saying it's an objective c data type or is it specific to cocoa or just C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the declaration `xmlChar` in `xmlString.h` found in libxml2 library as:

> ```
> typedef unsigned char xmlChar;
> ```

Now for `xmlChar to NSString` conversion

```
xmlChar *str = (unsigned char *)"I am to be converted";
NSString *convertedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)str];
```

from `NSString to xmlChar` conversion;

```
NSString *str = @"I am to be converted";
xmlChar *convertedString = (xmlChar *)[str UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Objective-C has any sort of xmlChar data type. In Cocoa, you will generally use an [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html), which just uses [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). Are you perhaps thinking of [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html)? In that case, it's simply defined as an `unsigned char` representing a UTF-8 octet (to help the compiler give warnings if you try to cast it to a `char`). You can generally treat an `xmlChar *` like a regular `char *`, as long as you keep in mind that it's UTF-8 encoded rather than in ASCII (so, truncating it may give invalid characters, comparing values to sort them won't work unless you implement locale-aware comparisons, etc).